# Open external storage directory on notification click

Tags: android, notifications, xamarin.android

I'm trying to open external storage directory when user clicks on notification but nothing happens. This is how I am doing it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath);

const int pendingIntentId = 0;
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
builder.SetContentTitle("...");
builder.SetContentText(notificationText);
builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.HgssLogoNotification);
builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

Notification.BigTextStyle textStyle = new Notification.BigTextStyle();
textStyle.BigText(notificationText);
textStyle.SetSummaryText("...");
builder.SetStyle(textStyle);

Notification notification = builder.Build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

const int notificationID = 0;
notificationManager.Notify(notificationID,notification);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do!

Comment: If user clicks notification, external storage should open. Is this clear enough?

Comment: Well your code will never do such a thing. Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath is just a path , why do you expect it to open anything?

Comment: What do you suggest then?

Comment: You can try using `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html, though I cannot figure out what is the use. The right thing to do, is launch your own class, and from there show the file chooser, and do something with it.

Comment: These are my thoughts: I am creating a file for user and to inform him about that creation, I push notification. Then when clicking notification, place where file is stored needs to be open. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Like I said, launch your own application and activity, then decide how to display. It will give you more control.